# How do you resize a window in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, browser, resize

I am working on an Angular app (1.6) which requires the window to be open in a particular size say 500px X 500px on load. After a few screens, the app resizes itself to a 150px X 400px window. To add to it, the app would be called by a third party vendor on initialization. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

I have been reading up on stack overflow and other forums, but can't seem to find an answer to it. There are topics on how to get the dimensions when the window is resized, but not actually resizing the window per se.

I have tried the following on body onload, using window.resizeTo but it doesn't seem to work.

Another way I can think of is to spawn a new window using window.open with the required dimensions and then resizing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was looking for this a while back, and the landing page opening the app in a certain size was the only way I found.

Comment: @z.bagley Thanks, so from what I understand, the only way would be the url being called by the third party and there's no way to resize the same window later, unless I spawn another window with the required dimensions?

Comment: That's what I found after lots of research.